# Getting Google App to work

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I've followed all the steps here https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine?_ga=1.82598931.449716086.1415074596 successfully up to step 5.3.  When I try to start the server:

```
dev_appserver.py appengine-try-python-flask
```

I get the following output:

```
-bash: dev_appserver.py: command not found
```

I'm on a Mac running OS X 10.10.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I'm running Python 2.7.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you didn't correctly add the dev_appserver (and other GAE tools) to the bash.
Did you restart your shell(s) to pick up the new environment changes?

If you did and the problem still persists, you can try downloading manually the GAE SDK.
After that, open the GoogleAppEngineLauncher, and just click OK on 'Make command symlinks'. This will solve your issue.

It's all easily explained in the official documentation:
[Download and Install the Google App Engine SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads)

Comment: I tried that.  When it begins installing, I get a failed to extract error then it says it couldn't find dev_appserver.py.  Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Did you try downloading the file again? You could try verifying the checksum just in case. Also it might be a matter of the proxy configuration, as I also faced some little trouble when installing the Google Plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: It's working!  I had to remove the old installation from the command line installation.  I didn't even know Google had kept the GUI interface.  When you type in Google App Engine, it shows this link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs then you click Try It and you get the link in my OP.  That's the command line install.  It seems broken though.  You have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: This worked for me: curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash (no slash at the end of google.com)

Comment: may try it at some point.  Not willing to now since it could screw up my install.  Thanks.